# Capturing key words from output in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I currently have a script that logs into a device and runs a command.
The results from the command are similar to this:

```
version: xxxx
date of installation: yyyyy
all other random stuff
which takes up a whole
lot of other lines
```

Since I am running this on many different devices (of the same type), the key words `version` and `date of installation` will always be the same.
I want to capture the `xxxx` and the `yyyy` which will be different depending on the device.

possibilities:

1. Capturing the whole output and using bash to isolate the word right after version: or right after installation:
2. using tcl itself to save the word after version: and installation: into a file

How do I go about doing option 2? 
I tried browsing through regexp of tcl, but couldn't come up with a solution

Revised code that is giving the error:

```
foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) "\n"] to set $line {
# if ([regexp {^version:} $line ] || [regexp {^date of } $line]){
     regexp {^version: (.+)} $line fullmatch vsn
     puts $fileId $vsn
     regexp {^date of installation: (.+)} $line fullmatch install
     puts $fileId $install
#}
}
```

was not too sure of the if statement so I voided it out. The rest of the code still returns an error saying no such variable for vsn

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're reading your output line by line, say into a variable `$line`, you can get the data you seek by applying the following matches:

```
regexp {^version: (.+)} $line fullmatch vsn
regexp {^date of installation: (.+)} $line fullmatch install
```

The `^` character anchors the match to the beginning of the line. In both cases the entire match is stored in `$fullmatch`, but the portion you want, which is matched within the parentheses, is stored in the second variable (`$vsn` for the first match and `$install` for the second match).

Comment: I was looking for this syntax, Thank you very much!

Comment: So it makes sense, but how do I read the output line by line, I was taking the whole output as such: expect_output(buffer)

Comment: In that case, you can set up a loop like `foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) "\n"]` to set `$line` to each line of the data, and then check for the regexps in the body of the loop.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Not quite. You will need the additional switch `-lineanchor` if you use that pattern.

Comment: Yea, the quantifier too should be lazy, or a negated class.

Comment: When I actually try to use the variables vsn and install, it gives an error: `no such variable`

Comment: Are you trying to use them just as `vsn` and `install`? To get their values, you need to use them as `$vsn` and `$install`.

Comment: I am using them as $vsn and $install, still returns an error, example:
`puts $fileId $vsn` and `puts $fileId $install`

Comment: In that case, perhaps your match isn't working, which might mean your data differs slightly from what you posted and if so, the pattern might need adjustment. Are you checking the return value from the `regexp` call to make sure it's not zero? The variables will only be valid when the return value is non-zero.

Comment: @SteveVinoski if the code in the answer is correct, which means the variable $vsn and $install is taking what is in the (.+) then no, the variables are not null So the way I am doing it is,, foreach $line splits the buffer based on \n (I tried \r too) , and then the 2 regexp statements. I tried using an if statement but it still returned an error

Comment: @user2883071in a tclsh I set a variable `lines` to your example in your question. I then ran `foreach line [split $lines "\n"] { if [regexp {^version: (.+)} $line fullmatch vsn] { puts $vsn } elseif [regexp {^date of installation: (.+)} $line fullmatch install] { puts $install } }` (with newlines after each open brace and after each `puts` call) and it worked correctly, printing `xxxx` and `yyyyy` as expected.

Comment: Thanks, the error was because I was using double braces in my `if` statement:
`if ([regexp {^version: (.+)} $line fullmatch vsn]) { puts $vsn }`